# How to create reqular expression to match number at the absolute end of text (without "\n")

Tags: ruby, regex

Example code:

```
test = "123knh8y78hah099ajs980"
test.scan(/\d+\Z/)
```

As a result, I should get:

```
=> ["980"]
```

It is correct. But if add the "\n" to the end of the text, regexp return 
incorrect result:

```
    test = "123knh8y78hah099ajs980\n"
    test.scan(/\d+\Z/)
 => ["980"]
```

Nothing changed, but the number is not the end of text. In the end of text symbol "\n".

Hot to create reqular expression to fix this problem?

Comment: using `\z` (lowercase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `\Z` with `\z` if you do not need to match `980` at the end of the string or before the final `\n` (which is matched with `\Z`).

See [Ruby Regex reference](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors):

> `\Z` - Matches end of string. **If string ends with a newline, it matches just *before newline***
>   `\z` - Matches end of string